# Open dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $G$ be an open dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. Prove that for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ there exists $a$ and $b$ belonging to $G$ such that $x=a-b$.

Comment: Can you add where you're stuck?

Comment: Interesting trivia: this is true if $G$ is a dense set with nonzero Lebesgue measure (it doesn't have to be open) or a dense, nonmeager set with Baire property. This is a consequence of Steinhaus theorem. This also generalizes to locally compact groups with Haar measure. But all of this is a bit too involved for such a basic question. :)

Comment: Sir, I haven't yet reached upto compact sets. Just started studying Metric spaces!

Comment: @MAB: That's what I thought, that's why I just post it as a trivia comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: If this was false, you could find $x$ such that $x+b\not\in G$ for every $b\in G$. That is $G\subseteq G^c-x$. Take the closure to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

1. Find a pont $b_0\in G$ and an open interval $(b_0-\epsilon,b_0+\epsilon)\subseteq G$ around it.
2. Given $x$, find a point $a\in G$ with $|a-(b_0+x)|<\epsilon$
3. Let $b=a-x$

Why do these three steps work?

Comment: for a given x how is it ensured that such a point a exists?

Comment: @MAB: $G$ is dense, so you can get arbitrarily close to any point, for example $(b_0+x)$.

Comment: Oh yes! thanks a lot Sir @tomasz